# How do I split different applications across multiple tcp ports on one site?

Tags: python, django

I have a series of applications which use one model and are all under one site.  Essentially a mix of the main website, and public and private api's. Is there a way to make different DJango apps use a different tcp port?  I have not been able to find anything in the documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

[Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/). Optionally, use Apache to setup a subdomain for each application so you don't have to remember all the ports.